# How to re-export namespace definition inside module declaration

Tags: typescript, types, lodash, typescript-typings

First of all I would like to understand why some TypeScript definition files are given in two flavors (I'll try to show this with `lodash` example).

The first one is "namespace based" (from `@types/lodash` definition):

```
export = _;
export as namespace _;
declare var _: _.LoDashStatic;
declare namespace {
    (...)
}
```

the second one is "module based" (from `typings` module definition):

```
declare module 'lodash' {
    var _: _.LoDashStatic;
    namespace _ {
        (...)
    }
    export = _;
}
```

Two definition sources of the same library show different approaches. What is the tradeoff here and why some typings from `@types/...` source are given in the first favor ant other in the second one?

I've encountered some problems with using "namespace based" definition with shared code that is located outside my project scope, so I prefer "module based" definitions.
Well, here comes the second step. I would like to standarize those definitions and only use `@types/...` source but when I get "namespace based" definition (like `lodash`) I would like to write some custom definition (as short as possible) that will re-export that namespace in a "module based" way.

I've tried something like this:

```
declare module "lodash" {
    import * as x from "lodash";

    var _: x.LoDashStatic;
    namespace _ {}
    export = _;
}
```

which of course does not work (besides no `cannot find module...` error any more), but I think pretty much shows what I'm trying to accomplish here.
My goal is to use the namespace declared in `@types/lodash/index.d.ts` and export it in different file (like `custom_typings/lodash.d.ts`) using module declaration.

To sum up two questions emerge:

1. Why definitions are build in two different ways?
2. How to simply translate one way approach to the other?

Answer (score 0):

After so much time searching for a solution for this, I finally got it working!

```js
/** index.d.ts */
import './models';

// tslint:disable-next-line:no-namespace
declare namespace MyLib {
    export interface A {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}


/** extra.d.ts */
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-module
declare module './index' {
    export interface B {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Both `A` & `B` are then accessible by consumers as part of the `MyLib` namespace.
Moreover you are properly able to access `B` inside the scope of the namespace defined in `index.d.ts`.

I agree that the syntax isn't great, but it does the trick.
A similar approach is used in lodash typings:

- https://unpkg.com/browse/@types/lodash@4.14.157/ts3.1/index.d.ts
- https://unpkg.com/browse/@types/lodash@4.14.157/ts3.1/common/common.d.ts

While in my above POC I preferred to use the es6 `import` syntax, the lodash typings use `/// <reference`. Both of these options work, so it's up to you to decide.